# How to pass parameters to a directive that will influence the choice of a template angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that could use one of 3 or 4 templates, depending upon parameters passed from a preceding page. If I cannot access scope variables when choosing which template to use inside the directive, how can pass the information to the directive. The first thing that occurs to me is to use the attributes of a directive tag that I dynamically write into the template, but I'm guessing that wouldn't work.

Comment: you guessed it correctly.you should pass details to your directive by  using attributes.by using  '=' two way binding.you should pass your template variable to that attribute.you can get the value of that attribute inside your directive.when ever the value changes that will automatically affected in your code due to two way binding .

Comment: Sundar - So I should use ngBindHtml to write my directive tag into my template containing the attributes that I want to pass to my directive. Does that work?

Comment: please give me some code or use the one i have added in my below answer

Answer (score 0):

you guessed it correctly.you should pass details to your directive by using attributes.by using '=' two way binding.you should pass your template variable to that attribute.you can get the value of that attribute inside your directive.when ever the value changes that will automatically affected in your code due to two way binding

for example i have a directive named my-directive component,

inside html

inside directive,

```
angular.module('directive',[]).directive('myDiretive', function(){
    return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: { template: '='  },
         template: '<p>ur template</p>',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
}
};

});
```

Comment: Sundar - To be clear, on a previous page I choose values that will influence which of 5 different templates I will want to use in my directive's 'template:' slot. Since I cannot use scope variables to make the choice of which template, how do I communicate to the directive which template to use? You say attributes, well good, but how do I dynamically change the attributes of my directive's tag? Can the directive's attributes's values be expressions that use $scope?

Comment: in the example i have given that directive has own scope because thats cut down from parents scope.so the directive cannot access anything inside the controller or anything.so if i need to pass data to directive i need t go with attributes.

Comment: so use equals binding while passing data to directive from controller.so whenever the data changes inside ur controller the data change will get reflected inside directive vice - versa

Comment: im creating an example